Software to validate large file backups, optimized for speed (Windows)
Please recommend Windows software to validate file backups.  The backups are not compressed, and are supposed to be byte-for-byte copies.
I'm looking for something optimized for speed.  Whatever is fastest (and accurate) is best.  I'm thinking that something that reads a file from the origin, stores it in memory, then reads the same file from the backup, and then compares the two files will not be very fast!
There are many techniques that can be used to make such an operation faster.  One technique I can quickly think of is to read each file from the source, creating checksum signatures (stored in a table or database) along the way, then perform the same operation on the backup, and then compare the checksums.  That's just a quick idea off the cuff, and I'm open to any solutions designed for fastest throughput.
The software needs to run on Windows.  Gratis (free of financial cost) is preferred, but I'm open to all options.  Also, portable (no install) software is preferred, but again, I'm open to all good solutions.  Open-source is a bonus, but not required.
The software needs to be able to handle over 1TB of data, and file sizes of that data range from 1 byte to 2GB.  The median file size is approximately 3MB.  The software will run on Windows 7 machine with 8-16GB RAM.

I'd use either SyncThing (free) or Resilio (paid).  Both will do the validation and the copyover too; if you have a faster way to do the copyover you can have that run in parallel.
